# how to replace multiple where clauses with signle associative array having same column and different conditions in ci

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

```
$this->db->where('column','value1');
$this->db->where('column','value12');
$this->db->where('column','value3');
```

I want to have something like

```
$where_array = array('column'=>value1,'column'=>value2,'column'=>value3);
$this->db->where($where_array);
```

Is that possible as we can not have same index name in associative array

Update:

Each condition differs from one another as below:

```
$this->db->where('column<','value1');
    $this->db->where('column>','value12');
    $this->db->where('column<=','value3');
```

Comment: Why would you want that to work? It would always return no rows, as it would require column's value to simultaneously match 'value1', 'value2' and 'value3'. In particular, it would produce a where clause like this one: WHERE `column` = 'value1' AND `column` = 'value2' AND `column` = 'value3'.

Comment: it makes no sense because at same time a single `column` cannot be equal to multiple values above `where()` will be evaluated as `where column='value1' and  column='value2' and  column='value3'` which will give 0 zero results

Comment: Actually i want to achieve a query like this: "select column from table where column <value1 or column >=value2 or column> value3"

Comment: @hussainfrotan can you update your question with all conditions you want to do in a query

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are doing `in` condition. then try below code.

```
$values= array(value1,value2,value3);
$this->db->where_in('column', $values);
```

For between operation

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/102635/

Comment: As far as i know in clause is used to compare the exact values what i am looking for is to have something like in('<100','>200','1000')

Comment: you have to mention your condition clearly in question. check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this like

```
$this->db->where(array('column'=>value1,'column'=>value2,'column'=>value3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your conditions differ from each other you cannot use `where_in()` or single `where()` clause, You can chain multiple where clauses to shorten the code as below

```
$this->db->where('column<','value1')->where('column>','value12')->where('column<=','value3');
```

However you do not need the first condition `->where('column<','value1')` because third condition `->where('column<=','value3')` is sufficient, so the final code would look like

```
$this->db->where('column>','value12')->where('column<=','value3');
```